# Why can't ES2015 classes be reliably transpiled in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, web-component, custom-element

I recently stumbled over the following statement on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements#Transpilers_versus_classes):

> Please note that **ES2015 classes cannot reliably be transpiled in** Babel 6 **or TypeScript** targeting legacy browsers. You can either use Babel 7 or the babel-plugin-transform-builtin-classes for Babel 6, and target ES2015 in TypeScript instead of legacy.

Is this statement just outdated for TypeScript > 3.x.x or could anyone explain what shortcomings there are for TypeScript transpilation?

I didn't notice problems when setting `target` to `ES5` in `tsconfig.json`, besides having to polyfill some more functionality (as expected).

Understanding those problems if they exist, would be really helpfull when dealing with custom elements and web components.

Comment: Given the babel plugin that it links to, I assume this is about transpiling classes that are or extend built-in classes.

Comment: I thought the same, but didn't find a proof or the detailed consequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the Github page of the [Custom Element polyfill](https://github.com/webcomponents/custom-elements#es5-vs-es2015), Custom Elements are defined as extensions of the `HTMLElement` class, which require a new ES6 feature that cannot be perfectly emulated with ES5 Javascript: `super()`/`Reflect.construct()`:

> The spec requires that an element call the HTMLElement constructor. Typically an ES5 style class would do something like HTMLElement.call(this) to emulate super(). However, HTMLElement must be called as a constructor and not as a plain function, i.e. with Reflect.construct(HTMLElement, [], MyCEConstructor), or it will throw.